# Make a call in twilio and get the record

Tags: java, twilio, wav

I am using twilio to make calls and record messages. Making the call and recording it is done (i can listen to the calls in the console of twilio). Now i want to get the call in .wav but i cant find how to do it. I only find how to get all the calls made. Is there any way to get the record after finishing the call. I am using java.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get a URL to the recording once it is completed by setting a URL for the `recordingStatusCallback` when you use [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback) or [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-recording-status-callback), or as the [`RecordingStatusCallback` parameter when recording a call made with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#recording-status-callback-parameter).

Whichever way you do that, when Twilio has completed generating the recording it will send an HTTP request to the URL you set as the callback. That request will have a `RecordingUrl` parameter, which will be the URL of the recording. If you add `.wav` to the URL, then you will get the recording in `.wav` format.

Let me know if that helps at all.